# Bandwidth-efficient, fail-safe database resync with long backlogs

Tags: replication, linux, data-synchronization

I'm looking for a DB system that allows slaves to resync even if there exists a long backlog. In addition these resyncs must be as bandwidth-efficent as possible as the nodes are connected over GSM/GPRS. A slave might be offline for several hours. All nodes run Linux.

I already looked at MySQL but it does not seem to fit the purpose as slaves might go out of sync and need to be reinitialized completely.

Please let me know in case the question is too vague.